# XSLT execute apply templates only once

Tags: xml, xslt, apply-templates

XSLT-

```
<Address>
<xsl:apply-templates select="Orders/Rows/Row[addres_no/number = $addr_no]" />
</Address>
```

Input XML-

```
<Orders>
    <Rows>
        <Row>
            <addres_no>
                <number>1</number>
            </addres_no>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <addres_no>
                <number>1</number>
            </addres_no>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <addres_no>
                <number>3</number>
            </addres_no>
        </Row>
    </Rows>
</Orders>
```

In the example above, I am executing a template if the address number matches the addr_no variable value.

I want the "apply-templates" to execute only once, even if multiple matches are found.

For example if $addr_no = 1, it would find two matches, but I only want to get the first available one.

I tried -

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Orders/Rows/Row[addres_no/number = $addr_no][1]" />
```

but that did not work.

Comment: Adding `[1]` should work. Please post a [mcve] so that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Does your actual XML have multiple `rows` elements in perhaps? In that case you should try doing `<xsl:apply-templates select="(Orders/Rows/Row[addres_no/number = $addr_no])[1]" />`